# Configuring aggregated table in import mode gives outdated data, so what is the use case?

Tags: powerbi

I have following model:

```
DimProduct: dual mode
DimStore: dual mode
FactSales: direct query mode
AggSalesByDate: import mode
AggSalesByProduct: import mode
AggSalesByStore: import mode
AggSalesByProductStore: import mode
```

The last 4 tables are configured as aggregated tables (auto hidden) of the FactSales table.

The import mode tables are refreshed once a day.

A table visual has columns that can be derived from the Agg table then it is showing outdated data. Whereas if the table visual has columns that don't belong to the agg table (which result in querying the fact sales table in direct query mode) then it gets latest data values.

Is this difference expected? This might be confusing to the users so I'm trying to understand what exactly is the use case if this aggregated tables feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what exactly is the use case if this aggregated tables feature?

To cache the data in memory for the most frequent aggregate queries instead of having to send queries to the back-end every time.  So your report's initial views are served from in-memory data, and only when the user drills down or adds additional filters or slicers do you need to send SQL queries to the data source.

Normally you refresh the aggregate tables every time you run ETL to update the data source, as this feature is intended to be used with batch-load data warehouse/data lake stores with fact tables too large to fit in memory, typically many billions of rows.

For caching with frequently updated data, the [Incremental Refresh with Hybrid Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-dataset-modes-understand#hybrid-tables) feature is more appropriate.

Comment: `Normally you refresh the aggregate tables every time you run ETL` in that case I can incrementally load the fact table as well. But I guess your point is the pre aggregation provides better performance?

Comment: If you can import the fact table, you should.  Aggregate tables are for fact tables that don’t fit in memory.